# MySQL pivot table to display different date as column

Tags: mysql

My MySQL table look like this :

```
id   product_id         date       
1         1           2018-3-22
2         2           2018-3-22
3         3           2018-3-22
4         1           2018-3-22
5         1           2018-3-20
6         2           2018-3-18
7         4           2018-3-22
8         1           2018-3-16
```

But in the output I want something like:

```
id  product_id    date1        date2   
1       1       2018-3-16    2018-3-20 
2       2       2018-3-18    2018-3-22
```

Here for product_id 1 has two rows with same date. So only one date will be counted. Means only different date will be counted.
And by querying maximum 2 date will be displayed per product_id.

if product has more than 2 different date then only 2 date will be displayed.

If product have only one date then no need to display.

I am trying to do this. But could not find any way to do this. Any help would be appreciated so much.

Comment: What if a product has more than 2 dates?  What if a product only has one?  How would you like to handle that if it is possible?

Comment: if product has more than 2 different date then only 2 date will be displayed.

If product have only one date then no need to display.